# Local variable referenced before assignment(speech recognition python)

Tags: python, google-speech-api

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
def speaking():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            text1 = r.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text1.lower()
    except:
        pass
    return text

text = speaking()
if text == 'hello':
    print("You said hello")
```

So yeah the code works fine. But whenever speech_recognition hears sounds like me clearing the throat/laughing/literally any ambient noise, I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZboe.png). Can you tell me why and tell a way to correct it?

Comment: What happens if any error is raised within that `try..except` block and `text = text1.lower()` isn't executed…!?

Comment: Don't use a bare `except` (use `except Exception` at the very least), and don't just ignore an unknown exception. At least log it, and you should re-raise it unless you are *certain* it is safe to ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem.

```py
def speaking():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            text1 = r.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text1.lower()
    except: # here its the problem
        pass
    return text # and here
```

the code should look like this

```py
def speaking():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            text1 = r.recognize_google(audio)
            text = text1.lower()
            # or you can return text here
            # and get rid of the below else block
            # return text
    except:
        # if you get an error then do nothing
        pass
        # you can return None
        return None
    else:
        # but if the try code worked then return text
        return text
```

ofcourse you get "referenced before assignment error" because in your old code if you get an error you do nothing with it and after that you reference text, but text isnt going to be defined if you get an exception just when you are recording.

Comment: A few lines of corrections helped me a lot! I appreciate the help mate.